# ¿Es correcto utilizar if($_POST){} en PHP para evitar warnings?

Tags: formularios, php8

estoy utilizando la versión 8.1.2 de PHP y me aparecen warnings como este:

Warning: Undefined array key "nombre"

lo que estoy haciendo, es un formulario con un text input para probar:

```
<input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu nombre" class="form-control input-md">
```

En PHP tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
        echo $nombre;
    }
?>
```

El formulario funciona, pero sin if($_POST) me aparece el warning antes de poner algo. Una vez le doy a enviar un nombre, se le asigna el valor al array y el warning desaparece.

Comprendo porqué me lanza el warning, la pregunta es ¿Es esta la forma de evitar este warning o es una chapuza?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso no lo pones para evitar el `warning` en si, que también, sino para detectar si el formulario ha sido ejecutado o no mediante el método **POST**.  ¿Sinó como sabrás cuando debes recuperar los datos enviados por POST con el formulario e interpretarlos y realizar acciones con ellos?

El caso es que si no pones el `if` entonces aparece el **warning**, pero puedes evitarlo facilmente con un operador de comparación denominado [operador de fusión de null `??`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) (en inglés en el manual pone **Null Coalescing Operator**) se haya enviado o no el formulario, de este modo:

```php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'] ?? null;
```

que basicamente es la forma abreviada de decir lo mismo que esto:

```php
if(isset($_POST['nombre']) {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
} else {
    $nombre = null;  // no le asignamos ningun valor en si o ponemos algo por defecto
}
```

Antes de la [versión 7](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) no existia el [operador de fusión de null  `??`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) y se podia hacer lo mismo de esta otra forma con el [operador ternario `?:`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```php
$nombre = (isset($_POST['nombre']))? $_POST['nombre'] : null;
```

pero era más feo y largo :-)

Comment: Qué simple con el operador ternario. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Fallo mio... he aclarado en la pregunta que no se llama así, el operador ternario es el otro `?:`... este se llama, de momento pendiente de traducir en el manual, **Null Coalescing Operator**

Comment: Buena respuesta. Pero, el [*operador de fusión de null*, que así se llama, existe desde PHP 7](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php), no desde PHP 8. Y, si asignas y en lo adelante usas la variable, el código queda mucho más claro y más limpio. O sea: `$nombre = $_POST['nombre'] ?? null; # En lo adelante usaremos $nombre para TODO y nos olvidaremos de $_POST ... if ($nombre) { # Usar $nombre } else { # $nombre es null, hacer lo que haya que hacer en ese caso }`

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias!  Yo es que me salté completamente la versión 7 y me fui directamente a la 8 desde la 5 y de ahí mi confusión :-)  Ya he editado mi respuesta con los enlaces pertinentes

Comment: Ok, la idea del comentario era precisamente esa, para que la respuesta quede mejor. Saludos.